# How can I do ajax call each time when store gets updated?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

How can I do an ajax call each time the store gets updated?

Basically, I want to fetch products with new API params, let's say there is a drop-down for items per page.  It is working fine on load, i.e on call of method `componentWillMount`

**But I'm not sure how to do a fetch again on when the store changes.**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ProductsList from '../components/ProductsList'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
// Action Creators
import doFetchProducts from '../actions/doFetchProducts'
import queryString from 'query-string'

class Products extends Component {

   constructor (props) {
     super(props);
   }

   componentWillMount () {
    this.fetch()
  }

  fetch () {

    let q = queryString.stringify({
      categories: 'rings',
      'attributes.Style': 'Classic',
      limit: this.props.applyItemsPerPage,
      page: 1,
      status: 'Active'
    })

    this.props.dispatch(
      doFetchProducts(q)
    )
  }

   render() {

    return (
      <section className="content">
        <ProductsList {...this.props} />
      </section>
    );
  }

}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    products: state.applyFetchProducts.products,
    isLoading: state.applyFetchProducts.isLoading,
    itemsPerPage: state.applyItemsPerPage
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(Products);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean you want to do the ajax call when component gets updated? You should be able to use `componentWillRecieveProps` for that. Check out: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Answer (score 0):

You can use Redux's [`store.subscribe`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html) to listen for changes.

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.unsubscribeStore = store.subscribe(this.onStoreChange);

  this.setState({
    currentState: store.getState()
  });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.unsubscribeStore();
}

onStoreChange = () => {
  const newState = store.getState();

  // Check the relevant part of store for changes.
  // Depends on your store implementation
  if (newState.reducer.prop !== this.state.currentState.reducer.prop) {
    this.fetch();
  }
}
```

`this.onStoreChange` will get called on each dispatch, so be careful not to create infinite loops. That is also the reason why you have to manually check for changes when the callback function is executed.